# Style a Slider Thumb with Styled Components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to style a slider with styled-components for React, but I do not get how I can style the thumb. I have a CSS that looks like this:

```
.faderInput::-webkit-slider-thumb {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border:1px solid black;
    ...
}
```

and my styled component looks like this

```
const FaderInput = styled.input`
    ...
    ::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        border:1px solid black;
        ...
  }
`;
```

Does anybody know how I can port this class selector to styled-components?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I actually got help. You have to add a `&` and then it looks like this:

```
 const FaderInput = styled.input`
 ...
 &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     width: 15px;
     height: 15px;
     border:1px solid black;
     ...
  }
```

Comment: Did you get it to work? My thumb styles aren't going through still.

Comment: I actually did, what did not work for you and how does it look?

Comment: I couldn't get any styles to come through onto the thumb. My main goal is to set a background image.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but as i recall a background image is not possible. But this here was the solution to restyle the thumb.

Comment: You saved my life

Answer (score 10):

This is what works well for me in Chrome and Safari. For FF you have to use this
[FF scrollbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars)

```
   const ScrollContainer = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 10px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
`;
```