# Custom styling an input slider using styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, slider, styled-components

I am trying to style a slider that I am creating using styled components. It should be a different color and should have an image for the thumb piece, but it is still the default blue, and the default thumb piece. I'm using bootstrap, so this slider styling must be the default for bootstrap.

[Other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47932710/6331353) which I've implemented in the code below aren't working. All I'm trying to do is to change the colour to something like yellow, and place an image overtop of the thumb piece.

[image]

```
import React from 'react';

import styled from 'styled-components';
import colors from 'styles/json/colors.json';

const image = './myImage.png';
const thumb = {
    width: 54,
    height: 26
}

const StyledSlider = styled.input`

    height: 5px;
    background-color: ${colors.colorScheme.secondary};
    outline: none;
    transition: opacity .2s;

    &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        width: ${thumb.width}px;
        height: ${thumb.height}px;
        border: 0;
        background: url(${image});
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 2px;
        background-size: 100%;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        outline: none;
    }

    &::-moz-range-thumb {
        width: ${thumb.width}px;
        height: ${thumb.height}px;
        border: 0;
        background: url(${image});
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: none;
        border-radius: 2px;
        background-size: 100%;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

`

export default (props) => (
    <StyledSlider type="range" {...props} />
)
```

---

**Update**
[Here's a code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-currying-uqlle?file=/src/App.js) of a tempermental solution. In my actual code the shadow doesn't line up perfectly with the line if I start messing with the margin. Also I can't figure out how to get this rounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you

> the code was written by @rblakejohnson but I did some changes

```js
import React from 'react';

import styled from 'styled-components';
import colors from 'styles/json/colors.json';

const image = './myImage.png';
const thumb = {
    width: 54,
    height: 26
}


const height = "36px";
const thumbHeight = 36;
const trackHeight = "16px";

// colours
const upperColor = "red";
const lowerColor = "yellow";
const thumbColor = "orange";
const thumbHoverColor = "#ccc";
const upperBackground = `linear-gradient(to bottom, ${upperColor}, ${upperColor}) 100% 50% / 100% ${trackHeight} no-repeat transparent`;
const lowerBackground = `linear-gradient(to bottom, ${lowerColor}, ${lowerColor}) 100% 50% / 100% ${trackHeight} no-repeat transparent`;

// Webkit cannot style progress so we fake it with a long shadow on the thumb element
const makeLongShadow = (color, size) => {
  let i = 18;
  let shadow = `${i}px 0 0 ${size} ${color}`;

  for (; i < 706; i++) {
    shadow = `${shadow}, ${i}px 0 0 ${size} ${color}`;
  }

  return shadow;
};

const StyledSlider = styled.input`
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  appearance: none;
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  height: ${height};
  cursor: pointer;

  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }

  &::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: ${height};
    background: ${lowerBackground};
  }

  &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    position: relative;
    appearance: none;
    height: ${thumbHeight}px;
    width: ${thumbHeight}px;
    background: url(${image});
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    box-shadow: ${makeLongShadow(upperColor, "-10px")};
    transition: background-color 150ms;
  }

  &::-moz-range-track,
  &::-moz-range-progress {
    width: 100%;
    height: ${height};
    background: ${upperBackground};
  }

  &::-moz-range-progress {
    background: ${lowerBackground};
  }

  &::-moz-range-thumb {
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
    height: ${thumbHeight};
    width: ${thumbHeight};
    background: ${thumbColor};
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 0;
    transition: background-color 150ms;
  }

  &::-ms-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: ${height};
    border: 0;
    /* color needed to hide track marks */
    color: transparent;
    background: transparent;
  }

  &::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: ${lowerBackground};
  }

  &::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: ${upperBackground};
  }

  &::-ms-thumb {
    appearance: none;
    height: ${thumbHeight};
    width: ${thumbHeight};
    background: ${thumbColor};
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 0;
    transition: background-color 150ms;
    /* IE Edge thinks it can support -webkit prefixes */
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      background-color: ${thumbHoverColor};
    }
    &::-moz-range-thumb {
      background-color: ${thumbHoverColor};
    }
    &::-ms-thumb {
      background-color: ${thumbHoverColor};
    }
  }
`;

export default (props) => (
    <StyledSlider type="range" {...props} />
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution kinda works but there's some tempermental things with it. In my actual code the shadow doesn't line up perfectly with the line if I start messing with the margin. [Here's a code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-currying-uqlle?file=/src/App.js) of your example with some fixes

Comment: @Sam Yes, you're right, in `lowerBackground` variable instead of dividing the with 2 try to dividing it with 3 like so  `trackHeight / 3`

Comment: That works a bit, with very specific margin-bottom values, the black line is too thick. It only happens with margin-bottom values of 10 and 11 in my actual code

Comment: @Sam Can you update the sandbox code so I can see that?

Comment: It's ok. That problem doesn't matter anymore. I ended up switching the shadow to the other side and making it the main color because I needed to make the one side thicker than the other. I'm having a problem with the space underneath the image not being colored though. I also don't know how to make the slider rounded. [Here's a new codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-browser-k5d1i?file=/src/App.js) showing my problem.

Comment: I'm having more problems with this slider. [I posted them on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65350101/multicolor-slider-using-an-image-with-transparent-cutout-as-the-thumb)

Comment: Sorry, [here's the right link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64671519/react-setting-a-dual-color-slider-thumb-to-an-image-with-transparent-background)

Comment: @Sam I saw the link, is it necessary to achieve that using `styled-component`? Actually, I can achieve the same design with different packages and it's easier to edit.

Comment: I’d like to use styled-components, a Json or scss. What package were you thinking?

Comment: What do you think using this package `material-ui-slider`? https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-slider

Comment: Or maybe this react-slider

Comment: I’d prefer not to, but if a material ui solution is the only one there at the end of the week, it’ll Get the bounty

Comment: I will take a look the the styled-component first then will see material ui.